# Prove that $\lim_{x \to 3} \frac{x-4}{x^2+2} = \frac{-1}{11}$ using the $\epsilon$ - $\delta$ definition of the limit.

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

We start with the definition of the limit:

$$\forall \epsilon , \exists \delta \text{ s.t.}$$

$$\left\vert f(x)-L \right\vert \lt\epsilon,$$
$$0\lt\left\vert x-a \right\vert \lt\delta$$

So we begin with some preliminary steps before writing out our proof:

$$\left\vert\frac{x-4}{x^2+2} + \frac{1}{11}\right\vert\lt\epsilon\Rightarrow$$

$$\frac{1}{11}\left\vert\frac{11x-44+x^2+2}{x^2+2}\right\vert\lt\epsilon\Rightarrow$$

$$\frac{1}{11}\left\vert x-3\right\vert\left\vert x+14\right\vert\left\vert\frac{1}{x^2+2}\right\vert\lt\epsilon\Rightarrow$$

Now I proceed to bound the $\left\vert x+14\right\vert$ and $\left\vert\frac{1}{x^2+2}\right\vert$ terms:

Say $\left\vert x-3\right\vert\lt2\Rightarrow$

$-2\lt x-3\lt 2$ $\space$ $\space$ which implies $\space$ $\space$ $15\lt x+14\lt19$

And here is where my problem arises. I don't know how to bound the $\left\vert\frac{1}{x^2+2}\right\vert$ term.

Any help would be appreciated, from hints to a well-established proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try to use the fact that
$$x^2\geqslant 0?$$

Comment: @SebastiánCórdoba What do you mean? Your work is really good. The $x \geqslant 0$ is a hint to bound $\frac{1}{x^2+2}$ from above.

Comment: So would it be wrong to try and follow these steps? x^2>=0, x^2+2>=2,       
 [1/(x^2+2)]<=2. Would this be correctly bounded?

Comment: @SebastiánCórdoba You are almost right: you just need to take the reciprocal of $2$ as well: $\frac{1}{x^2+2}\leqslant \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Yes, you are right. Very dumb mistake. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @SebastiánCórdoba You're welcome. Thank you for showing your work and using latex in your post :)